# How to create the app icon on current screen?

Tags: ipad, ios

When installing a new app, and even though i have space left in my home screen, why does it create a new screen and create the icon there?

Is there any configuration to, when installing a new app, the icon be created to fill the space in already created screens?

Comment: Are you open to jailbreaking? It's probably not worth it for a small nuisance such as this, but they do add up…

Comment: @0942v8653 yes i'm open to jailbreak options

Comment: This is certainly for distinguishing between the factory apps and the user-installed apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New apps are never installed to the first screen.  Instead, they are put in the first open space available from the second screen onward.  If there is no open space for the app, then a new screen is created.

This does seem like something that could easily be turned into a preference; and, there may be a jailbreak setting already.  But there is currently no way to override this behavior that is supported by Apple.